# customizing Spree home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am running Spree in my ruby on rails application, and I am using the spree_fancy theme (if that matters). This is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there is this text "Welcome to our amazing store! Choose anything you with, we'll ship it anywhere!"

I want to modify the text displayed there and add some other markup.

I downloaded the spree source code from github, and basically there is a home controller that is loaded when calling route url:

```
#frontend/config/routes.rb
root :to => 'home#index'

#frontend/controllers/spree/home_controller.rb
def index
  @searcher = Spree::Config.searcher_class.new(params)
  @searcher.current_user = try_spree_current_user
  @searcher.current_currency = current_currency
  @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
end

 #views/spree/home/index.html.erb
 <%= render :partial => 'spree/shared/products', :locals => { :products => @products } %>

 #spree/shared/_products.html.erb
 ...
```

Basically, I followed the whole call sequence, and I cannot find the view that contains this text anywhere (and I highly doubt it is stored in database).

Where is the view that contains this home page information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the source for the home page in spree_fancy here:

https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/97ca1c823979871f5cf16f0b6cd1d5ddca960cb6/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb#L8

You have two options for replacing this content:

1. Use [Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) to customize this content
2. Copy the view from spree_fancy to your application @ app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb and customize the content

Both of these options are described in more detail in the [Spree Developer View Customization Guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/view.html)

Comment: Yep, no wonder, spree_fancy had their own template. Do you happen to know if they are using a css grid system? i notice when I inspect the css I see a lot of classes called columns three, columns four, columns five, etc. So I am wondering if they are using a popular grid system.